# Rust: Replace function on struct

Tags: testing, rust, mocking, monkeypatching

I have the following code which I'm trying to test. My question is how do I replace the function something that's implemented on B? So that under test B.something does nothing, or returns a specified value?

```
trait DoSomething {
    fn something(&mut self);
}

struct A {}
struct B {}

impl DoSomething for A {
    fn something(&mut self) {
        println!("doing something on A");
        let mut b = B{};
        b.something();
    }
}

impl DoSomething for B {
    fn something(&mut self) {
        println!("doing something on B");
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = A{};
    a.something();
}
```

The above code is available in the [rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b1ece308073b127ea675cadae13dc9e0)

Coming from python I would simply patch.object(b, 'something')

Comment: You may also find it useful to use `#[cfg(test)]` to mark code as compiled only in test builds.